# If $f: M\rightarrow N$ is a homomorphism, is this implication $(L + f(K) = N \Rightarrow f^{-1}(L) + K = M)$ always true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the book Rings and Categories of Modules of Anderson and Kent Fuller at page 73 Lemme 5.18, we have the following : 
If $K\ll M$ and $f: M\rightarrow N$ is a homomorphism, then $f(K)\ll N$....
The proof starts with this:  Let $L\leq M$ and assume $L + f(K) = N$. Then $f^{-1}(L) + K = M$.... I have some problem to prove this implication. Could someone help proving the implication ?

Comment: hello @user26857,  $f^{\leftarrow}(L)$ is the preimage of $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to prove and I think you could have tried a little harder.

Let $x\in M$. Then $f(x)\in N$, and from $L + f(K) = N$ we get $y\in L$ and $x'\in K$ such that $f(x)=y+f(x')$. It follows $x-x'\in f^{-1}(L)$, so $x=(x-x')+x'\in f^{-1}(L) + K$.

Comment: Thank you very much @user26857.  Effectively the proof is easy. :)